# How to search for a value in an array of objects that contain nested objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I want to develop this functionality for searching/filtering a list. Basically, I'll get a search term from an input box and then I have to get all the items that include the search term from an array.

Here's what I've tried so far, it works for root level properties but doesn't work with nested arrays/objects:

```js
// Filter List
this.filterList = query => {
  if (typeof query === "string") {
    // transform query to lowercase
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    // clear the current list being displayed
    this.filteredList = [];
    // filter the lsit and store the results with
    // matching criteria in "filteredList" array
    let filteredResults = _.filter(this.itemList, item => {
      if (item && typeof item === "object") {
        // loop over the item object
        for (let property in item) {
          if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            let key = item[property];
            // address, phone and emails
            if (typeof key === "object" && _.isArray(key)) {
              _.filter(key, element => {
                if (typeof element === "object") {
                  for (let nestedProperty in element) {
                    let nestedKey = element[nestedProperty];
                    if (nestedKey) {
                      nestedKey = nestedKey.toString().toLowerCase();
                    }
                    if (nestedKey && nestedKey.includes(query)) {
                      return item;
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
            } else {
              if (key) key = key.toString().toLowerCase();
              if (key && key.includes(query)) return item;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    // assign the filtered results to the list being displayed
    this.filteredList = [...filteredResults];
  } else {
    // if query is empty or null or anything other than string
    // revert all changes and assign the original list to display list
    this.filteredList = this.itemList;
  }
};
```

If it helps, here's an object from the array that I am looping over:

```
[
  {
    "id": "number",
    "dealerCode": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "gstin": "string",
    "pan": "string",
    "cin": "string",
    "emails": [
      { 
        "name": "string", 
        "address": "string", 
        "isPrimary": "boolean"
      }
    ],
    "phoneNumbers": [
      { 
        "countryCode": "number", 
        "number": "number", 
        "isPrimary": "boolean"
      }
    ],
    "addresses": [
      {
        "addressLine1": "string",
        "addressLine2": "string",
        "addressLine3": "string",
        "country": "string",
        "state": "string",
        "city": "string",
        "postalCode": "number",
        "isPrimary": "boolean"
      }
    ],
    "status": "string",
    "statusId": "number"
  }
]
```

I am doing this in AngularJS and using Lodash as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem like this where you need to compare a heterogenous list of primitives and object/arrays, a recursive named function is usually the best way to go. This should probably solve what you're looking for, based on the following assumptions:

1. All entries by a user as treated as strings. So 99 and "99" are the same. I'll comment in the code where this assumption is made
2. All entries are case insensitive (all converted toLowercase)
3. There is no set depth of the nested objects/arrays; the solution below works recursively for any depth of a heterogeneous list
4. If *anything* matches in any leaf node, the entire object will be returned

The way the solution works below is:

- Filter through the top level list and call matchesEntryInTree on each dataItem, compared to the userEntry
- matchesEntryInTree will check each dataItem and see if it's an array or object

  - If the dataItem is an array/object, we drill into them again by calling matchesEntryInTree recursively
  - If it isn't, we call compareValues to see if the entry matches the current dataItem
- With the recursive pattern above, all leaf nodes (regardless of the shape of the tree) will be compared to the initial userEntry

```js
// test data for trial runs
const testData = [
  {
    id: 123488,
    dealerCode: "ACb3",
    name: "Some Name",
    gstin: "string",
    pan: "string",
    cin: "string",
    emails: [
      {
        name: "Some Email name",
        address: "anemail.domain.com",
        isPrimary: "boolean"
      }
    ],
    phoneNumbers: [
      {
        countryCode: "9398",
        number: "number",
        isPrimary: "boolean"
      }
    ],
    addresses: [
      {
        addressLine1: "Florida",
        addressLine2: "Street place",
        addressLine3: "string",
        country: "string",
        state: "string",
        city: "string",
        postalCode: "number",
        isPrimary: "boolean"
      }
    ],
    status: "string",
    statusId: "number"
  },
  {
    id: 88888,
    dealerCode: "NMC",
    name: "Some Other",
    gstin: "string",
    pan: "string",
    cin: "string",
    emails: [
      {
        name: "An Email thing",
        address: "athing.somewhere.org",
        isPrimary: "boolean"
      }
    ],
    phoneNumbers: [
      {
        countryCode: "93948",
        number: "number",
        isPrimary: "boolean"
      }
    ],
    addresses: [
      {
        addressLine1: "Denver",
        addressLine2: "Street place",
        addressLine3: "string",
        country: "string",
        state: "string",
        city: "string",
        postalCode: "number",
        isPrimary: "boolean"
      }
    ],
    status: "string",
    statusId: "number"
  }
];


// broke these into separate helper functions, but you can combine all of them except the recursive one if you'd like
const returnFilterResults = (userEntry, dataItems) => {
  const compareValues = (entry, dataValue) => {
    if ( _.isBoolean(dataValue)) {
      return entry === dataValue;
    } else if (_.isNumber(dataValue)) {
    // if the dataValue is a number, we convert both it and the user's entry (which probably already is a string) to a string to compare
    // you can make this comparison more strict if desired
      return _.includes(_.toLower(_.toString(dataValue)), _.toLower(entry));
    } else if (_.isString(dataValue)) {
      return _.includes(_.toLower(dataValue), _.toLower(entry));
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const matchesEntryInTree = (entry, dataItem) => {
  // if this dataItem is an object or array, let's drill back in again
    if (_.isObject(dataItem) || _.isArray(dataItem)) {
      // as we recursively move through the tree, check to see if *any* of the entries match, using 'some'
      return _.some(dataItem, innerDataItem => {
        return matchesEntryInTree(entry, innerDataItem);
      });
    } else {
    // if it's a primitive, then let's compare directly
      return compareValues(entry, dataItem);
    }
  };

  // I created a results variable so we could console log here in this snippet
  // but you can just return from the filter directly
  const results = _.filter(dataItems, dataItem => {
    return matchesEntryInTree(userEntry, dataItem);
  });

  console.log(userEntry, results);
  return results;
};

returnFilterResults("place", testData);
// both entries return

returnFilterResults("Denver", testData);
// second entry is returned

returnFilterResults(48, testData);
// both entries return - ID in first, countryCode in second

returnFilterResults(12, testData);
// first entry is returned
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: That looks promising. How can I miss such simple logic - Recursion! Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it solved your problem, please mark my answer as the solution to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a flatten function to flatten your object/JSON then search for your value? An example for this is the following:

```
var flattenObject = function(ob) {
    var toReturn = {};

    for (var i in ob) {
        if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
            var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
            for (var x in flatObject) {
                if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;

                toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
            }
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
};
```

For a nested object, let's say

```
{
  A : {
    B: {
     C: "V"
    }
  }
}
```

you'll get an object with the key A.B.C and the value "V". This way, you'll only have one level to search your value in.

Hope this helps!
Cheers!